# Spring Boot Thymeleaf render image as base64 string

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail

I am trying to make an email template which contains a QR code as an image, for that I am creating a base64 encoded string for the qr code image but when I am sending that image in email it is not showing there.
    In the email template I am accessing the base64 string as

```
<img th:attr="src=${base64Data}"
```

And the template engine is creating the html as follows:

```
<body><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

But when I receive the email it does not show the image.If I add an alt attribute to the image then the alt text is visible but the src attribute is missing from the img tag in the email.

Comment: What mail reader are you using to display the mail?

Comment: @BillShannon I am using gmail web and mobile app.But does it matter here?

Comment: Yes, it matters because not all mail readers will display messages identically.  I would've expected Gmail to display the image in your case, but I haven't tested it myself.  Many mail readers won't display remote images by default, but I would've expected inline images to be displayed.  If you can convert the image to image/jpeg format perhaps that will help?